# Javascript control like iOS indexed table view?

Tags: javascript, uitableview

I'm building a mobile webapp and I'd like to recreate the interface element of the alphabetic index that appears on the right side of the iPhone contacts app. I'm not sure what this is called and I can't find any example implementation. jQuery mobile doesn't seem to have it either.

I'm about to roll my own but I wanted to see if this existed first. It's got to respond to touch/drag events and show the currently selected letter as you drag over it. Anyone know of an existing javascript implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch Framework provides this functionality.
Either way if you want to build a mobile app responding to touch events, using a framework is a must.

This functionality is a combination of the List+IndexBar components on Sencha Touch.
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.IndexBar

Answer (score 0):

So I started writing a simple javascript list component, modeled after the iOS UITableView. It's a work in progress and I'm putting in just what I need. Sources are here https://github.com/shyam-habarakada/js-virtual-list-view. Contributors needed :-)